# 02 (str) - 1 (int) = 01 (str) How to get result like this?

Tags: php, string, int

```
<?php

$str = "02";
$int = 1;

$result = $str-$int;

echo $result // 1

?>
```

But I need result = 01

Don't tell me `"0".$str-$int;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = "02";
$int = 1;

printf('%02d', $str-$int);
```

or

```
<?php
$str = "02";
$int = 1;

$result = sprintf('%02d', $str-$int);
// do something with $result here
```

see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: If I want to make variable ?

Comment: @l2aelba you would use `sprintf()` instead. +1 this is a better solution.

Comment: l2aelba: then you'd use sprintf as shown at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14216162/4833

Answer (score 4):

try

```
printf("%02d",$str-$int);
```

The explanation of the numerous formatting possibilities of printf are explained [in the sprintf docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?

$str = "02";
$int = 1;

echo sprintf("%02d", (int)$str - $int);

?>
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_pad()](https://www.php.net/str_pad) where you set it to pad the left with 0's until the length of string is 2 chars.

```
echo str_pad($str - $int, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: @l2aelba, I would use VolkerK's answer as it is a better approach to do it.